How do you model the two-way interactions between a continuous variable and two factors but not the three-way interaction with GAMs?
For the example, let's suppose I'm trying to model the level of activity of some frogs depending on a continuous variable (water temperature) and two factors : their sex (M or F) and the period of the day ("night" or "day"). I want to know if males and females have a different level of activity, regardless of the time of day, and if frogs are more active at night or during the day, regardless of their sex. I'm not interested in the difference between sexes depending on the time of day or between night and day depending on the sex. Is the following model correct to test that (syntax for the gam function from the mgcv package in R) ?
model = gam(activity ~ sex + period_of_day + s(water_temp, by = sex) + s(water_temp, by = period_of_day), data = data, family = tw, method = REML)

I'm wondering if I'm not including the main effect of water_temp twice using this syntax but I'm quite new to GAM so I'm not sure.
Thanks for your help.

While the model you showed could work without problems for your data, it is, as you wondered, including the "main" effects of water temperature multiple times.
A more stable way of estimating this model would be to fit an average smooth for water_temp over all the data, and then fit your two by smooths as orthogonal difference smooths, using the "sz" basis:
m1 <- gam(activity ~ s(water_temp) +
    s(water_temp, sex, bs = "sz") + 
    s(water_temp, period_of_day, bs = "sz"),
  data = data, family = tw, method = "REML")

Note that with this basis, unlike the factor-by smooths, you don't need to include the factors as parametric effects as the group means are included in the basis for the sz smooths.
While you might not be interested in differences between sexes in the night or day, the frogs might be doing different things? For you to use the statistical outputs from your model for inference, you do need to ensure your observations are independent conditional upon the model. In other words, if the activity of the two frog sexes does differ between day/night etc, you need to model this effect if you want the credible intervals and p-values to have the correct coverage.
You can of course determine if the difference in activity levels among sexes by period of day is biologically important or not by fitting the full three-way model and looking at the estimated effect sizes for the three-way smooths:
m2 <- gam(activity ~ s(water_temp) +
    s(water_temp, sex, bs = "sz") + 
    s(water_temp, period_of_day, bs = "sz") + 
    s(water_temp, sex, period_of_day, bs = "sz"),
  data = data, family = tw, method = "REML")

I would actually just fit m2 and be done with it — if the effects are small then they will be doing very little to your model's fitted values, and as you're going to have to use adjusted predictions to interpret this model anyway (because you have the effect of water_temp spread over three smooths already with the first model (m1)), including another set of smooths (m2) won't change that or make the interpretation any easier.
What I mean by adjusted predictions is you are going to want to predict from your model for a grid of values evenly spaced over the range of water_temp, repeated for all combinations of sex and period_of_day:
library("gratia")
ds <- data_slice(
  m2,
  water_temp = evenly(water_temp),
  sex = evenly(sex),
  period_of_day = evenly(period_of_day)
)

fv <- fitted_values(m2, data = ds)

Then you can plot the fitted values in fv using ggplot() (most easily) or using plot(), to show the estimated smooth effects of water_temp in the combinations of sex and period_of_day.
You could use a model comparison statistic to choose between the two models, but unless you know for a fact that the $f_{\mathtt{sex}:\mathtt{period}(i)}(\mathtt{water\_temp}_i)$ (three way interaction) effect is exactly zero, you are using your data to select your model and the statistical summaries computed on the resulting model don't know anything about this and they will be wrong. Instead, just use m2 if there is any doubt as to the biological relevance of $f_{\mathtt{sex}:\mathtt{period}(i)}(\mathtt{water\_temp}_i)$. And if you must show just the sex (period_of_day) differences, then use the exclude argument to mgcv:::predict.gam() to exclude those other effects. For example, to show just the sex differences, ignoring the effects of period_of_day in the fitted values (but remember we estimated the effects of sex in the presence of the other smooths)
# dropping period_of_day will choose the reference level as we have
# to provide something to `mgcv:::predict.gam()`, but this period
# effect will not be included in the fitted values if we exclude
# the smooths / terms it appears in
ds2 <- data_slice(
  m2,
  water_temp = evenly(water_temp),
  sex = evenly(sex)
)

# check I have the right smooth names with
smooths(m2)
# you want to list the names of the smooth involving `period_of_day`
excl <- c("s(water_temp,period_of_day)",
          "s(water_temp,sex,period_of_day)"))
# you could probably also do:
# excl <- smooths(m2)[1:2]
# but check you have selected the right smooths for exclusion
fv2 <- fitted_values(m2, data = ds, exclude = excl)


Hello @Gavin. Thanks for your detailed answer it helps a lot. I was wondering how I could include another continuous variable and it's interactions in the model. Let's say I want to add the effect of a contaminant's concentration in the pond (var name = cont) on frog's activity depending on the frog's sex and the water temperature. Is the following syntax correct (see next comment) ? Also I don't know what's the policy on asking another question in the comments. I guess it's not in the good practices of the forum. Should I juste create a new post all together ? Thanks.

m2 <- gam(activity ~ s(water_temp) + s(water_temp, sex, bs = "sz") + s(water_temp, period_of_day, bs = "sz") + s(water_temp, sex, period_of_day, bs = "sz") + s(cont) + ti(cont, water_temp) + s(cont, sex, bs="sz") + s(cont, water_temp, sex , bs="sz"), data = data, family = tw, method = "REML")
I'd like to estimate the main effect of the contaminant on frogs activity, the effect of its interaction with the water temperature (affects the frogs response to changes in the water temperature) and how that varies depending on the frog’s sex.

@Boussens-DumonGrégoire Can you add that as an edit to your question, or ask this as another question. What you suggest isn't going to give the right effect, but explaining why and what to do instead is going take quite a few comments and it would be better as an Answer to a Question.

Hi @Gavin, it's done. You can find the question here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/648762/384937). Sorry for the delay in creating it I've been quite buzzy. Thanks for your help.
