How to model the interaction between two continuous variables and two factors using gams with mgcv?
I was wondering how I could model the effect of two continuous variables X1 and X2 and two factors F1 and F2 and their interaction on a outcome Y using gams. What I primarily want to know is (in parenthesis are the gam syntaxes giving me the estimates for the effect I'm interested if the only variables in my model were the ones named in the bullet point) :

the effect of X1 on Y depending on F1 (Y ~ s(X1, by = F1))
the effect of X1 on Y depending on F2 (Y ~ s(X1, by = F2))
the effect of X2 on Y (Y ~ s(X2))
the effect of the interaction between X1 and X2 on Y (Y ~ s(X1, X2))

The other effects I'm less interested in but would be curious to know how to include in my model are :

the effect of X1 on Y depending on the interaction between F1 and F2 : (Y ~ s(X1, by = interaction(F1,F2)))
the effect of X2 on Y depending on F1 (Y ~ s(X2, by = F1))

The two reasons I'm less interested in those effects are 1) biologically speaking, I don't expect them to be very significant, and 2) I don't want to consume degrees of freedom unnecessarily because I also have several other predictive variables in my model. But I can still test it, as suggested by @Gavin Simpson here (How do you model the two-way interactions between a continuous variable and two factors but not the three-way interaction with GAMs?) and see if it comes out significant or not and if I'm overfitting or not. Here is my attempt at a model for all these effects using orthogonal difference smooths :
model = gam(activity ~ s(X1) + s(X1, F1, bs = "sz") + s(X1, F2, bs = "sz") + s(X1, F1, F2, bs = "sz") + s(X2) + s(X2, F1, bs = "sz") + ti(X1, X2), data = data, family = tw, method = REML)

I'm not sure how the ti term fits within the whole thing when using orthogonal smooths.
Last thing, if I want to add a random effect associated to the sampling team (calling that variable) ID for example, I can just add s(ID, bs="re") to the model right ?
Thanks for your help.

The model for your first set of bullets can be fitted as
y ~ s(x1) +
    s(x2) +
    s(x1, f1, bs = "sz") +
    s(x1, f2, bs = "sz") +
    ti(x1, x2)

Adding in the interaction of both factors with continuous x1 can be done with
y ~ s(x1) +
    s(x2) +
    s(x1, f1, bs = "sz") +
    s(x1, f2, bs = "sz") +
    s(x1, f1, f2, bs = "sz") + # <----
    ti(x1, x2)

The ti() smooth is fine here; it doesn't contain the basis functions that are generated by the main effect smooth s(x1) or s(x2), so it is pure interaction. As this model already contains both those smooths for the "main" effects (really average smooths), everything works out just fine with this model setup
It gets trickier when you want to have two continuous variables interacting with the same factor because the sz basis includes the group means of the factor(s) and hence if you try s(x1, f1, bs = "sz") + s(x2, f1, bs = "sz") the group means will be modelled via two sets of terms and that way lies a unidentifiable model. The final model you show is going to have this problem and if it even fits at all, will tend to have some terms that have large uncertainties because of the identifiability.
You can try this:
y ~ s(x1) +
    s(x2) +
    s(x1, f1, bs = "sz") +
    s(x1, f2, bs = "sz") +
    s(x1, f1, f2, bs = "sz") +
    s(x2, by = f2, m = 1) + # <----
    ti(x1, x2)

where we shift the penalty to the first derivative of the smooth so that it should be identifiable against the main effect smooth s(x2). The problem with this is that this smooth doesn't use a basis that is orthogonal to that of s(x2), so it's not quite the same thing as the sz basis.
If you really need to go down this route, I would likely switch to modelling the smooths at each level of the factors using by smooths. If we drop the "average" smooths (the s(x1) and s(x2)) then we don't have an identifiability issue with the by smooths, so:
y ~ f1 + f2 + f1:f2 +
    s(x1, by = interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE)) +
    s(x2, by = interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE)) +
    ti(x1, x2)

It seems a bit odd to  have the "main" effects vary by the two factors but not the smooth-interaction. So I would think this would the model to fit
y ~ f1 + f2 + f1:f2 +
    s(x1, by = interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE)) +
    s(x2, by = interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE)) +
    ti(x1, x2, by = interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE))

or, simpler if you don't need the decomposition:
y ~ f1 + f2 + f1:f2 +
    te(x1, x2, by = interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE))

All the by mechanism does with factor is to arrange for a separate smooth for each level of the factor
And ideally you'd make the interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE) a variable in your data set
data <- data |>
  transform(f1f2 = interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE))

so you can just use by = f1f2 in your model code.
Yes, s(f, bs = "re") will generate a term that is equivalent to Gaussian random intercepts.
